# CSS: Place Bootstrap input's label above it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap in my design and I need to place the input's Label above it but the labels are currently sitting next to the inputs which causes the inputs not to be 100% width.

This is an example of the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/od5Lc5cz/1/

and my current code is:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">

<label for="gst">Commission</label>
    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
    <input id="coms" type="text" class="form-control" name="coms" placeholder="Commission" value="">
  </div>
  </div>
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Comment: Your "form" example has no `<form>`

Comment: @j08691 `<form>` is completely unnecessary given the problem expressed.  The above code represents the almighty Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @RobertC I was simply noting the fact that there's no actual form here. I didn't ask for a [mcve] did I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code organization is incorrect, as `.input-group` is designed to collect the items in a single line.  The solution is to move your `<label>` outside that class:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="gst">Commission</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
        <input id="coms" type="text" class="form-control" name="coms" placeholder="Commission" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you had your `<div class="input-group">` on the wrong line.

https://jsfiddle.net/od5Lc5cz/2/

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="gst">Commission</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
    <input id="coms" type="text" class="form-control" name="coms" placeholder="Commission" value="<?php echo $coms; ?>">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use so:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
   </div>
</div>
```